# Script to unhide a google sheets row doesn't work consistently

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am just learning to play with scripts and cannot get a script to hide and show a specific row to work on the sheet I want to apply the script to.  I have a google sheet I created as a sandbox where it does work but once I copy the script and assign the script to a button the "show" function does not work while the hide function continues to.

All I'm trying to do is hide row 3 and then be able to unhide the same row on this sheet.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function hide() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
  spreadsheet.getRange('4:4').activate();
};

function show() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('4:4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().showRows(3, 1);
};
```

There are no errors, the script runs to completion without any visible changes to the sheet(the row is still hidden)

Comment: If you didn't this yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: The title says "Script to hide a google sheets row doesn't work consistently", but on a comment to my answer you says that the hide part works fine. please edit your question to clarify what works and what don't .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/**
 * This hides the row 3 of the active sheet.
 *
 */ 
function hide(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.hideRow(3);
}
```

The above code is a simplified version. Since you want to hide only one row, use it use `hideRow(rowNum)`.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowrow

Comment: The hiding works with the code I started with.  The issue I'm having is with the "show" function to unhide the row after it was hidden.

```
function show() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.showRows(3);
```

doesn't show the row after it was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider highlighting the row and clicking "group row". This will create a collapsing + button that will show/hide that row on the left hand side of the page